# SublimeText and the ignore_vcs_packages setting

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

My SublimeText experience is nowadays dominated by the tight Git integration that it wants and fails to provide. Messages as shown below pop up everywhere and all the time.

On the internet there are many who try to provide solutions to this nagging problem using the `ignore_vcs_packages` setting. This setting can receive a Boolean true for all or array of specific packages to ignore. Purportedly, because all different variations of this setting fail to work.

Is it still possible to use SublimeText when Git is also installed? How can we get rid of these messages?

[image]

```
Package Control

Error executing: /usr/bin/git config --get branch.deploy.remote

Working directory: /home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SomePackage



VCS-based packages can be ignored by changing the "ignore_vcs_packages" setting to true.

Sublime Text will need to be restarted once the setting is changed.
```

Comment: What file did you put the setting in?

Comment: Fixed it. Installing and activating a theme and color scheme added a `ignored_packages` section which seems to overrule the `ignore_vcs_packages` setting. After removing `ignored_packages` setting error messages not longer appear.